# customise gridview display when bound to a datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display the values in a gridview in this way(image),how can i perform it,i have no idea,if i have to edit the column or add template fields.,please help.
If we add,a footer,it can be displayed only on the last row,but,how to make it be displayed in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using something like a `Repeater` or `DataList` control, which give you more control over the output.

Comment: Nice solution as repeater will give you a very nice control over the design as it do not leaves any signs of itself, like we have in grid and datalist

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdv" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Exam Date
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("Exam_Date") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Section
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("Section") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Total Students
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("Total_Students") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            No. of students passed
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%#Eval("StudentPassed") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            over all pass percentange
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <%#Eval("Overall_Percent") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On cs page:

```
gdv.DataSource = YourDataSource;
gdv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do a column spanning to have this look. (I am assuming you have all the data needed to bind to the control.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview Footer for this display .

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
   <FooterTemplate>
   <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text="NAME"></asp:Label>
     </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

On RowDataBound Event you can set your total to label .

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
      {
         Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
         lbl.Text = "Total";
      }
   }
```